# Batch parsing json file with colons in value

Tags: json, batch-file

I have a `json` object like this that I'm trying to parse in `Batch` (no `powershell`):

```
{
  "name": "a_name",
  "number": 111,
  "parameters": {
    "field1": "a value: with colons, and commas",
    "field_i_want": "True",
    "another_field_i_want": "Valid"
  },
  "more_fields": "values"
}
```

I need to extract True (or False) as one variable and Valid (or other possible string values) as another variable but I'm having trouble with it because of the colons and commas in field1 which are variable. What I have so far relies on a consistent number of colons so it breaks down.

I think it would be better to find the string "field_i_want" or "another_field_i_want" then get the substring following that until the next comma or brace. However, I'm having some trouble doing this; could someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I cant offer you a script that accepts json path and you'll need to hardcode the json object members into the script:

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "jsonFile=.\content.json"
::echo %jsonFile%|mshta.exe "%~f0"|more

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('echo %jsonFile%^|mshta.exe "%~f0"') do (
    echo %%#
)

exit /b %errorlevel%

<HTA:Application
   ShowInTaskbar = no
   WindowsState=Minimize
   SysMenu=No
   ShowInTaskbar=No
   Caption=No
   Border=Thin >

<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.visible=false;
    window.resizeTo(1,1);

   var fso= new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1);
   var fso2= new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(0);
   var json=fso2.ReadLine();

   var fso3=new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

   var file = fso3.OpenTextFile(json, 1);

    var strText = file.ReadAll();
    file.Close();

   var obj = JSON.parse(strText);
   //fso.Write(strText);

   fso.Write(obj.parameters.field_i_want + "\r\n");
   fso.Write(obj.parameters.another_field_i_want + "\r\n");
   window.close();
</script>
```

for this you'll need at least internet explorer 9. The script uses `mshta` which is basically internet explorer with an access to the file system.It uses it's internal json parser. I think I can come up with a version that does not flashes the small mshta window.

Comment: hey, thanks for this - I actually ended up writing a python script and using the build in json parser and then calling that through the Batch file